# UITableView background color iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9

I have a UITableView that I want to set its background color to transparent. Background color for the table view and all subviews at interface builder is set to transparent. It works fine for iOS 8 & 7. but, not iOS 9. any idea?

**cellForRowAtIndexPath method:**

```
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: First, this is not a good idea because the scrolling performance will suffer. Apart from that, I think it's a bug. File a radar.

Comment: have to tried `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` ? try digging a little more, before reporting.. hmm.. i'm also thinking that it's a bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Objective-c:**

```
[self.yourTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

**Swift:**

```
self.yourTableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

XCode 7.0 bug. Not picking up from Storyboard

Comment: Yes I figured that out before.

Comment: does this bug still there in beta 5? did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying beta 5.

Comment: @hasan83 Yes this is still a bug in beta 5

Comment: I have similar issue with constraints - for some screens they're just disappear.

Comment: I think this is an ios9 bug rather than an xCode bug. An app build for ios8 with Xcode 6 is giving a white UITableVIewBackground colour

Answer (score -1):

This happens to me even when creating an UITableView in code, and setting it as a private property of my UIViewController. However, if the UITableView is a global variable, this problem does not occur.

I suspect Apple is rooting around the ivars on my UIViewController, setting UITableView's background colors to UIColor whiteColor without asking me. I have checked, and the calls to do go through setBackgroundColor on the UITableView.